# Selfhosted Secure WCF by Id password using net tcp

Tags: c#, wcf, security

I want to self host a WCF service requiring an ID and password.

This [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/433463/Selfhosted-Secure-WCF-by-Id-password-custom-valida) does exactly what I need

The only problem is since I am using the service to excenge messages between to console applications it will be nice if I could use the NetTcpBinding instead of BasicHttpBinding.

Also how secure is BasicHttpBinding? **I need to securely send messages between client and server (both client and server are self hosted wcf services(they are console applications))**

Comment: have you tried changing `BasicHttpBinding` usages in that example to `NetTcpBinding`?

Comment: Yes I get an exception stating that I need an SSL certificate. I might have to create one.